# Complementary events multiplied

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I don't understand the solution of the following problem :

"A woman as a set of n keys, one of those opens the door. If she discards the ones that don't fit, what is the probability that she opens the door at the k° try?? What is the same probability if she didn't discard those which don't fit?"

The first answer is 1/n, which already seems strange to me since everytime she uses 1 key that doesn't work she has 1 less key to use.

The second answer is 1/n*(((n-1)/n)^(k-1)), why do we multiply complementary events elevated to the number k??

Comment: For the first:  the winning key has an equal chance of being in any of the $n$ positions.  For the second:  she must fail $k-1$ times and then succeed.  Each trial is independent of the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If she discards keys, then we have probability of succeeding to open on try $k$ as

$$
\mathrm{Pr}(\text{Fail on try } 1)\cdot\mathrm{Pr}(\text{Fail on try } 2)\cdot
\ldots\cdot\mathrm{Pr}(\text{Fail on try } k - 1)\cdot\mathrm{Pr}(\text{Open on try } k) = \\
\frac{n - 1}{n}\cdot\frac{n - 2}{n - 1}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{n - (k - 1)}{n - (k - 2)}\cdot\frac{1}{n - (k - 1)} = \frac{1}{n}.
$$

In case she doesn't throw away wrong keys we have just the geometric distribution with probability of success $1/n$, so

$$
\mathrm{Pr}(\text{Open on try } k) = \mathrm{Pr}(\text{Fail } k - 1\text{ times})\cdot\mathrm{Pr}(\text{Succeed}) = \Bigl(1 - \frac{1}{n}\Bigr)^{k - 1}\cdot\frac{1}{n}
$$